# Showing error 'ViewHolder' is an abstract class cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a custom recyclerView adapter but it's show error in onCreateViewHolder.

How to instantiate abstract class ?

What's the problem in my code ?

I have checked other answers too all said that your name must be duplicate or you must have imported wrong class but none of them helped.

A suggestion would be great considering me in a learning phase.

```
public class RegisteredRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RegisteredRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public Context context;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RegisteredRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.registered_item_listview,parent,false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        return  new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RegisteredRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: No any XML Layout. No any Error report.... How can we help you without minimum informations?

Comment: You are returning a wrong ViewHolder object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to create an instance of `RecycleView.ViewHolder` not `RegisteredRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder` in `onCreateViewHolder()` method. Since `RecycleView.ViewHolder` is an `abstract` class, you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return new ViewHolder(view);`

Answer (score 0):

as @Amin said you are trying invalid return in onCreateViewHolder() try below

```
 @NonNull
@Override
public RegisteredRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.registered_item_listview,parent,false);
    context = parent.getContext();
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    return  new RegisteredRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder(view);  //change here
}
```